# Creating a row of boxes in Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am attempting to create a row of boxes in illustrator. Each box would be right next to one another. Trying to avoid hard coding each one because I need 60 of them.

I have tried to find several arrays, but they aren't functioning. Possibly because Illustrator and the web have differences in syntax.

```js
var doc = app.documents.add(null,1920,1080);

{

    var fillColor = new RGBColor();

    //fill color
    fillColor.red = 100;
    fillColor.green = 100;
    fillColor.blue = 100;

    var p = doc.pathItems;

    var rect1 = p.rectangle(540,0,300,300);
    rect1.filled = true;
    rect1.strokeWidth = 0;
    rect1.fillColor = fillColor;
}    

function draw ()
{
    var spread = rect1
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    rect1[i].show();

}
```

As of now, I am not getting any errors. All that is happening is I'm getting a single grey box on the left side of my layout (which is expected since I obviously didn't write this all correctly).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom function to achieve this. For instance:

```js
// Create a new Illustrator document.
var doc = app.documents.add(null,1920,1080);

// Specify a fill color
var fillColor = new RGBColor();
fillColor.red = 100;
fillColor.green = 100;
fillColor.blue = 100;

/**
 * Creates a row of equal sized boxes.
 * @param {Object} pos - The specification for the row of boxes.
 * @param {Number} pos.startX - The x position for the first box.
 * @param {Number} pos.startY - The y position for the first box.
 * @param {Number} pos.width - The width of each box.
 * @param {Number} pos.height - The height of each box.
 * @param {Number} numberOfBoxes - The number of boxes to draw.
 */
function createRowOfBoxes(pos, numberOfBoxes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; i++) {
    var rect = doc.pathItems.rectangle(pos.startY, pos.startX + i * pos.width, pos.width, pos.height);
    rect.filled = true;
    rect.strokeWidth = 0;
    rect.fillColor = fillColor;
  }
}


createRowOfBoxes({
  startX: 0,
  startY: 1080,
  width: 32,
  height: 32,
}, 60);
```

---

**Explanation**

- The custom `createRowOfBoxes` function utilize a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) statement to create multiple boxes. In the body of the `for` statement each box is generated. Note that during each turn of the loop the part which reads;

  ```js
  pos.startX + i * pos.width
  ```

  is what essentially changes the `X` position so that each box is positioned right next to one another.
- The last part that reads:

  ```js
  createRowOfBoxes({
    startX: 0,
    startY: 1080,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
  }, 60);
  ```

  invokes the custom function. In this example we pass two arguments:

  - An Object with values for; `startX` and  `startY` - these specify where the first box in the row should be positioned. The `width`, and `height` values specify the width and height for each box.
  - The number of boxes to include in a row, e.g. `60`